# Prisma errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, prisma

I'm trying to create a middleware to log request information for a NextJS app to gather browser information for some analytics. The frustrating problem I'm having is that I'm trying to add another relationship similar to one I already have working but I get an error.

schema.prisma

```
model Request {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  userId      String?
  url         String
  ip          String?
  //userAgentId Int
  user      User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  //userAgent UserAgent  @relation(fields: [userAgentId], references: [id])
}

model UserAgent {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  name    String
  browser String
  engine  String
  os      String
  device  String
  cpu     String
  //requests Request[]
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  email         String?   @unique
  role          Role      @default(USER)
  name          String?
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  deletedAt     DateTime?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  requests      Request[]
  //userAgentId   Int?      @db.UnsignedInt
}
```

The above Prisma schema works but as soon as I uncomment those lines to add the relationship between Request and UserAgent I get this error:

```
Error: Can't create table `dillanjwilding`.`Request` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
   0: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::migration_step
           with step=AddForeignKey { foreign_key_id: ForeignKeyId(1) }
             at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/apply_migration.rs:21
   1: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::apply_migration
             at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/apply_migration.rs:10
   2: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:433
```

It's confusing to me because the code is almost identical to the relationship that works. Other proposed solutions suggest it's the order in which the tables are created but I've tried moving them around my `schema.prisma` file and it doesn't seem to change anything. I can't seem to figure out how to show the underlying MySQL so I'm having difficulty pinpointing exactly what's wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been elusive and frustrating for days but I finally realized the problem. The error seems ambiguous because it seems so generic which threw me off. I needed to modify the columns on `Request` to match the columns on the tables they are referencing. Since they were unsigned integers I needed to make the integers unsigned as well, like this:

```
model Request {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  userId      String?
  url         String
  ip          String?
  userAgentId Int     @db.UnsignedInt
  user      User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userAgent UserAgent  @relation(fields: [userAgentId], references: [id])
}
```